# What are the different types of Ananda

Tags: spiritual-level

Within the word Sat Chit Ananda is the word Ananda What is the difference between the Red Bindu Ananda the Spiritual Union Ananda and the Golden Loka Ananda

Comment: What do you mean by red and golden ananda?

Comment: Taittariya Upanishad (Brahmananda Valli) has one verse dedicated to describe Ananda.

Comment: @Uday Krishna ya to let go of desire let's you receive.

Comment: Are u asking about the different kinds of spiritual bliss? @FrankHestermann

Comment: @Rickross ya via the senses and via  extra sensory perception the conscious mind experiences many things and gives them names. 3 of those  things are the Anandas above. Please explain the cause of these Blisses and what are there names for these blisses ?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what exactly you mean by Red Bindu Ananda and Golden Loka Ananda. Here is one verse that discuss about different types or levels of Ananda from Brahmananda Valli of [**Taittiriya Upanishad.**](https://archive.org/details/AitareyataittiriyaUpanishadsWithShankaraBhashya-English)

> II-viii-1-4: Out of His fear the Wind blows. Out of fear the Sun rises. Out of His fear runs Fire, as also Indra, and Death, the fifth.
>
> **This, then, is an evaluation of that Bliss:**
>   Suppose there is a young man - in the prime of life, good, learned, most expeditious, most strongly built, and most energetic. Suppose there lies this earth for him filled with wealth. This will be **one unit of human joy**. If this human joy be multiplied a hundred times, it is **one joy of the man-Gandharvas**, and so also of a follower of the Vedas unaffected by desires. If this joy of the man-Gandharvas be multiplied a hundred times, it is **one joy of the divine-Gandharvas**, and so also of a follower of the Vedas unaffected by desires. If the joy of the divine-Gandharvas be increased a hundredfold, it is **one joy of the manes whose world is everlasting**, and so also of a follower of the Vedas unaffected by desires. If the joy of the manes that dwell in the everlasting world be increased a hundredfold, it is **one joy of those that are born as gods in heaven**, and so also of a follower of the Vedas untouched by desires. If the joy of those that are born as gods in heaven be multiplied a hundredfold, it is **one joy of the gods called the Karma-Devas**, who reach the gods through Vedic rites, and so also of a follower of the Vedas unaffected by desires. If the joy of the gods, called the Karma-Devas, be multiplied a hundredfold, it is **one joy of the gods**, and so also of a follower of the Vedas untarnished by desires. If the joy of the gods be increased a hundred times, it is **one joy of Indra**, and so also of a follower of the Vedas unaffected by desires. If the joy of Indra be multiplied a hundredfold, it is **one joy of Brihaspati** and so also of a follower of the Vedas unaffected by desires. If the joy of Brihaspati be increased a hundred times, it is **one joy of Virat**, and so also of a follower of the Vedas untarnished by desires. If the joy of Virat be multiplied a hundred times, it is **one joy of Hiranyagarbha**, and so also of a follower of the Vedas unsullied by desires.

In other words,

```
1 joy of Human            x 100 = 1 joy of Human Gandharva  
1 joy of Human Gandharva  x 100 = 1 joy of Divine Gandharva
1 joy of Divine Gandharva x 100 = 1 joy of Pitru
1 joy of Pitru            x 100 = 1 joy of Ajanaja Deva
1 joy of Ajanaja Deva     x 100 = 1 joy of Karma Deva
1 joy of Karma Deva       x 100 = 1 joy of Deva
1 joy of Deva             x 100 = 1 joy of Indra
1 joy of Indra            x 100 = 1 joy of Brihaspati
1 joy of Brihaspati       x 100 = 1 joy of Prajapati
1 joy of Prajapati        x 100 = 1 joy of Brahma
```

Ananda/Bliss is one Swarupa of Brahman.

Comment: Ahhh to reach the land "That's Beautiful". Electric .

Comment: Krishna loka is the place to be, a lot of Ananda there.

Comment: @FrankHestermann Krishna loka? do you mean GoLoka?

Comment: Ya but i believe it has a few other names .

Comment: @FrankHestermann Btw, have you noticed - all these Ananda are also attained by those who doesn't have any desires?

Comment: Hiranyagarbha is the keshetra of anada I was looking for re the golden Ananda. Now to find the name for Bindu Ananda. Maybe just Red Bindu Ananda. And then the name of  the Orgasmic Ananda not of the flesh but of the Spirit.

Comment: @FrankHestermann What is Red Bindu? can you provide some references? Is it related to any Chakra?

Comment: The Red Bindu is a Siddhi center in the middle of the forehead above the eyebrows. Many Hindus mark this spot with a red dot as a symbol of remembrance. The center enables one to experience the keshetra known as Prakriti. When opened the essence of all form is  seen as being red and within the Bindu , all that is is within this ocean and one is filled with an Ananda, the level of Ananda can be raised. I can not find a name for this Ananda.